# How to show show more and show less link if text size is more than specified pixel in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to show show more text only if the p tag is more than 40px height and if the text expands on click of show more, it should change to show less. So how can I check the condo if the text size is more than 40px ? Kindly help.

```
 <p class="expandable"  ng-class={expanded:show}>long text-------</p>
    <a ng-if="!show"  ng-click="show=true">show more</a>
    <a ng-if="show"  ng-click="show=false">show less</a>

CSS:

.expandable {
 line-height:40px;
Overflow:hidden;
}

.expanded{
line-height:auto;
}
```

Comment: test size or text length ?

Comment: I have checked content length. It's working only in desktop view. But when it comes to mobile view, line height and content length differs. So I need to check if the content is more than line height I want to show more link

Answer (score 1):

Hi referer this  https://plnkr.co/edit/gfQmrD1mRvF81QXp7C8C?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<p class="expandable hideContent"  ng-class=showclass>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
       ghjgjgjkghkk jkhkj
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.-</p>
   <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#" ng-click="showmore()">{{showtest}}</a>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.showtest = 'ShowLess';
  $scope.showmore = function(_logout) {
    if($scope.showtest == 'ShowMore')
    {
       $scope.showtest = 'ShowLess';
       $scope.showclass = 'hideContent';
    }
    else
    {
      $scope.showtest = 'ShowMore';
      $scope.showclass = 'showContent';
    }

  }
```

using the Line-height i implement the class

**CSS**

```
/* Put your css in here */

.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: check your plunker link. it is not having your code.

Comment: sorry i updated my link i dint save thats y no ok already thank you @StarkButtowski

Comment: I want to show "showMore" and showLess only if the text overflows and exceeds the height of expandable class. Suppose if give small text or just two lines of text within the specified height. Then "showMore" and "showLess" link should be hidden. How can i change this